# Argument principle and the residue

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, summation, holomorphic-functions

How to prove $\int_{\gamma}f'(z)g(z)dz/f(z)=2\pi i \sum^N_{j=1}g(\alpha_j)$, where f and g are holomorphic functions and $\gamma$ is a simple closed curve such that no zero of f lies on $\gamma$. And suppose $\alpha_1, \alpha_2,... \alpha_N$ are the zeroes of f in $Int(\gamma)$.

I think this can be considered as the generalization of the argument principle, but don't know how to prove this problem. Thanks.

Comment: since $f(z) = H(z) \prod_{j=1}^N (z-\alpha_j)^{e_j}$ where $H(z)$ has no zeros, then $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = h(z) +\sum_j \frac{e_j}{s-\alpha_j}$ where $h(z) = \frac{H'(z)}{H(z)}$ is holomorphic. So it is really a generalization of the [Cauchy integral formula/theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) (as the residue theorem and the argument principle)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Around a zero of order $k$, $f$ can be represented as $$(z-z_0)^kh(z)$$ with $h$ holomorphic and $h(z_0)\neq 0$. Noe apply the product rule and Cauchy's theorem.

EDIT: let $f(z)=(z-\alpha_i)^kh(z)$ as in the hint. Then $f'(z)=k(z-\alpha_i)^{k-1}h(z)+z-\alpha_i)^kh'(z)$, and hence
$$\frac{f'}{f}=\frac{k(z-\alpha_i)^{k-1}h(z)+z-\alpha_i)^kh'(z)}{(z-\alpha_i)^kh(z)}=\frac{k}{z-\alpha_i}+\frac{h'}{h}.$$
The first summand has a simple pole, the second is holomorphic.
By Cauchy's theorem one has, for any holomorphic function $g$ and any simple closed path around $z_0$
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{g}{z-z_0}dz=g(z_0,)$$
And for any closed path
$$\int_\gamma gdz=0.$$
Conclude

Comment: How to connect it with the zeros of $g(z)$?

Comment: You don't have to treat those separately, as if $g$ is zero at some zero of $f$, then $g(\alpha_i)$ will be zero, hence no contribution on the right hand side...

Comment: But we don't know if g will be 0 at some zero of f?

Comment: in general writing $\frac{f'}{f}(z) = \frac{d}{dz} \log f(z)$ makes it even more obvious

Comment: @J.doe why a zero of $g$ would change something ?

Comment: @user1952009 I'd rather avoid using $\log$ when dealing with complex integration...

Comment: @b00nheT you shouldn't. Locally $\log f(z)$ is holomorphic, and its derivative is meromorphic, so no problem of branches.